# How to change title of my html page written on spring framework which used apache tiles

Tags: java, apache-tiles

I am new to web development, I got a git project which is made with spring mvc and in web-inf folder I saw something tiles, later researched I got to know Apache tiles is used, I did some formatting to the html pages. I wanted to change title a of the html page. but I am not getting any file where I can change it. have any one Idea how to change the title of HTML.

PS: it is a  pre-written code, I tried

```
<title> My tile </title>
```

tag in the html page but it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See you in you webapps folder.

you will see a configuration file like tiles.xml or tilesconf.xml etc.

see there will be a tag as attribute name = "title" change the text to your title.

```
<definition name="XXXXXXXX" extends="baseLayout">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="YOUR TITLE HERE" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/views/myjsp.jsp" />
</definition>
```